# How to fill a multi select input from a hidden input and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

So I have an address book tool that I setup using this http://www.phpkobo.com/address_book.php. I also setup Select2 which is a jquery plugin that manages multiple select inputs https://select2.github.io/examples.html.

So this address book tool does not allow you to setup a multi select input so i had to engineer my way around this by creating a multi select input that then copied your selected input into a hidden input. Using the below script I managed to get the selected items copied over automatically over to a hidden input i had.

```
function loopSelected()
{
  var txtSelectedValuesObj = document.getElementById('hidden_input');
  var selectedArray = new Array();
  var selObj = document.getElementById('selected_items');
  var i;
  var count = 0;
  for (i=0; i<selObj.options.length; i++) {
    if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
      selectedArray[count] = selObj.options[i].value;
      count++;
    }
  }
  txtSelectedValuesObj.value = selectedArray;
}
```

So this script works just fine however, the problem is that when I got to edit an entry my multi select input is empty since all the data was saved on the hidden input. Im trying to figure out how can I fill the multi select input with the data that's already in the hidden input and vice versa?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is an example of what I got working:
https://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/1956/

Comment: With this type of question you will have far better results if you attach a demo jsfiddle to your question.

Comment: Sure thing here is a link the jsfiddle of what I have working at the moment. https://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/1956/

Comment: Ive been searching on google for examples but still having no luck. Im looking looking at alternatives to my issue which would be asking the owner of the tools to provide custom work but dosen't come cheap lol. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some help via this thread [Jquery script - Fill select with input text and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550966/jquery-script-fill-select-with-input-text-and-vice-versa/28551105?noredirect=1#comment45418180_28551105)

Here is the final product working as desired: http://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/1966/

```
 $("#txt").bind('keyup' , function(e){
    var ar = $(this).val().split(",");
    $("#sel option").each(function(){
        if(ar.indexOf($(this).val()) != -1)
           $(this).attr("selected","selected");
    });
  });
$('#sel').change(function(){
    $('#txt').val($('#sel').val());
});
```