# Jquery script - Fill select with input text and vice versa

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 scripts that I need to combine, I basically have a script that allows a text input to be filled when you select an item in a select list. I also have a script that fills a select list based on input of a text input. Now I am trying to figure out how can I combine these 2 scripts so they can work together.

Heres an example of a multi select filling a text input. 
http://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/1963/

```
    function loopSelected()
{
  var txtSelectedValuesObj = document.getElementById('hidden_input');
  var selectedArray = new Array();
  var selObj = document.getElementById('selected_items');
  var i;
  var count = 0;
  for (i=0; i<selObj.options.length; i++) {
    if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
      selectedArray[count] = selObj.options[i].value;
      count++;
    }
  }
  txtSelectedValuesObj.value = selectedArray;
}
```

Heres an example of a text input filling a multi select based on input.
http://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/1964/

```
  $("#txt").change(function(e){
    var ar = $(this).val().split(",");
    $("#sel option").each(function(){
        if(ar.indexOf($(this).val()) != -1)
           $(this).attr("selected","selected");
    });
  });
```

What I am trying to accomplish is something like this:
If text input is null then fill text input with selected option from the select list.
If the text input is already filled then fill in the multi select based on input from the text input.

Any help would be appreciated.

Final update:
Finally got the results I wanted, here the final product http://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/1966/ been working on this for weeks possibly months lol. Really happy to have this working.

Comment: Fiddles not working, WHen i select it does not fill the input

Comment: Strange it was working fine when i set it up. ill try it out once im back on my pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added another change script function, seems to have made it work. Your change set the selected, and mine transfers the values.

```
$('#sel').change(function(){
    $('#txt').val($('#sel').val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/akhyp/1965/

Comment: Is it normal that when i type in a value in the text input i have to hit enter for it to transfer?Ii was hoping it would recognize the input and transfer as soon as it finds a match. I had the same problem with my original script could figure that one out.

Comment: It should be triggered on enter or blur off if you use .change(). You can try .click() or .keyup() and see if those behaviors are more what you had in mind.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip i managed to get it working with keyup as you suggested. For those curios here is the final product. http://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/1966/

Comment: I notice, that if a user types something in that doesn't match something in the box, then selects an option from the box, it deletes the previously entered text. If that's a feature/validation, then you should keep that. If that's a bug, then you'd need to rearrange some of the logic.

Comment: Well after reviewing my current setup, I have a text input which is dynamically filled and that same input is read only so users cannot modify it. So after re-assesing the code some one provided me with a much simpler solution http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/akhyp/1984/. This is working great for me and it eliminates the need to work on any logic.

Comment: I didn't want to change that logic, because that may be applied to something else outside scope of this question.  In other words, that splicing might be used outside of the context of changing the value of the multiselect.  Later on if you need to splice that string, but when input comes from somewhere else (like a previous form, or a database) you would need to repeat the splice again or refactor your code. I'm glad you got to a solution that works for your current needs!